# I need to Customize the serializer in ember.js Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, crud, struts2-rest-plugin

My server needs json in the below format when sending a PUT request.
My server is a rest api designed using struts2 rest plugin.

```
{
id: "5",
empId: "5",
firstName: "oki", 
lastName: "iko", 
edQual: "phd"
}
but the RESTAdapter serializes it to
[
employees:
 {
  id: "5", 
  empId: "5", 
  firstName: "oki", 
  lastName: "iko",
  edQual: "phd"
 }
]
```

I tried ignoring properties in backend but that just ignored the whole json and submitted null values to the sql-server.
I need to override or customize the Serialization of ember.js but I dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the responsibilities for the Serializer provided by Ember Data. I guess you are using `RestSerializer`, which is normally used together with `RestAdapter` aren't you? In that case you should customize the [`serializeIntoHash()` method](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.13/classes/RESTSerializer/methods/serializeIntoHash?anchor=serializeIntoHash). Just not using a namespace at all should be accomplished by:

```js
import RESTSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/rest';

export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash(data, type, record, options) {
    data = this.serialize(record, options);
  }
});
```

To not loose any data that is already present on `hash` you could use `Object.assign()`. This is also what's done in [`JSONSerializer`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.13.1/packages/serializer/addon/json.js#L1061):

```js
import { assign, merge } from '@ember/polyfills';

const emberAssign = assign || merge;

export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash(hash, typeClass, snapshot, options) {
    emberAssign(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
  },
});
```

The `assign || merge` is only needed to support very old ember versions. You could simplify to:

```js
import { assign } from '@ember/polyfills';

export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash(hash, typeClass, snapshot, options) {
    assign(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
  },
});
```

You don't need to use the polyfill for `assign` if you don't support IE 11. In that case it would be:

```js
export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash(hash, typeClass, snapshot, options) {
    Object.assign(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
  },
});
```

And with native class it looks like:

```js
export default class ApplicationSerializer extends RESTSerializer {
  serializeIntoHash(hash, typeClass, snapshot, options) {
    Object.assign(hash, this.serialize(snapshot, options));
  }
}
```

Comment: thnx so much. this worked!!!. I knew i had to override some method but I didnt understand which to override.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Please be aware that you need additional configuration for reading data in that format.

Comment: You mean overriding the normalizeResponse method right?